# C two-way pipes between parent and child

Tags: c, unix, fork, pipe

I've got a structure that contains (among other things), two sets of file descriptors.

```
int (*pfdsParent)[2], (*pfdsChild)[2]
```

They are assigned memory when I malloc the other arrays in my struct,

```
s -> pfdsParent = malloc(3 * x * sizeof(int))
s -> pfdsChild = malloc(3 * x * sizeof(int))
```

The struct contains information from each line in a file, this information is used to create a process for each line in the file. The child process executes a program, and the pipes need to be bidirectional (or rather, there needs to be two pipes for each). My first question is about 'assigning' the values of these file descriptors. In examples I've seen you just do something like,

```
 int pfds[2]; 
 pipe(pfds);
```

So I thought that you wouldn't need to initialize these descriptors. But then if I'm in a loop trying to access,

```
(s -> pfdsChild[i][0])
```

Does it know that I'm talking about the stdin of the child for the i'th process I'm creating? I don't get any errors/warnings on those lines but it confuses me how it could work like that if I've never indexed it. Anyways, second question is about communication between parent and child. My (limited) understanding of pipes led me to the function,

```
int pipeFork(struct *s, int* Length){

    int i, status;

    for(i = 0; i < *Length; i++){

        char *args[] = {(s-> Name[i]), (s-> Args[i]), NULL};

        pipe(s-> pfdsParent[i]);
        pipe(s-> pfdsChild[i]);

        if(!fork()){ // child 
            // parent stdout goes to child stdin (read from child) 
            dup2((s-> pfdsChild[i][0]), (s-> pfdsParent[i][1])); 
            close((s-> pfdsParent[i][0])); 
            close((s-> pfdsChild[i][1])); 

            // child stdout goes to parents stdin (read from parent)
            dup2((s-> pfdsParent[i][0]), (s-> pfdsChild[i][1])); 
            close((s-> pfdsParent[i][1]));
            close((s-> pfdsChild[i][0])); 

            execvp((s-> Name[i]), args);

         } else{ // parent 

            dup2((s-> pfdsChild[i][0]), (s-> pfdsParent[i][1])); 
            close((s-> pfdsParent[i][0])); 
            close((s-> pfdsChild[i][1]));

            dup2((s-> pfdsParent[i][0]), (s-> pfdsChild[i][1])); 
            close((s-> pfdsParent[i][1]));
            close((s-> pfdsChild[i][0])); 


            write(s-> pfdsParent[i][1], "test", sizeof("test")); 
            wait(&status); \\ see if child gets it 
    }


return 0; 

}
```

The program which the child execs into tries to do,

```
read(stdin, buffer, sizeof(buffer)); 
printf("I have %s\n", buffer); 
printf("Child done!\n);
```

But it doesn't receive the string from the parent at its standard input. Is there something terribly wrong with what I've done? The end goal is for me to be able to print from the child and have the parent read it, and print stuff to the child from the parent. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You declare the parent and child as a pointer to an array of 2 int with `int (*pfdsParent)[2]`. If you want it to be a multi-dimensional array pointer, you may have meant `int** pfdsParent`

Comment: With all those file descriptors it's easy to get lost. A complete runnable program would be nice. One thing that's definitely missing is any attempt to connect any of the pipes to the actual stdin and stdout of the child process. When you exec a new process, it always looks to fd 0 for stdin and fd 1 for stdout, so you should be dup2'ing *something* to fd's 0 and 1.

Comment: @BrainSteel, I think the way I've declared them is okay. A pointer to an array of 3 ints. I've declared the strings in my array as (*stringname)[100] (i strings of length 100) and it works as I expect it too, unless it behaves differently for arrays?

Comment: @WumpusQ.Wumbley, so just looking at the child process, the two dup2 calls I use don't actually connect the pipes to stdin and stdout? The comments above the first two dup2 calls describe my understanding of what it's doing, are they incorrect? Or are you saying I need 4 dup2 calls each for parent and child?

Comment: I don't understand how you think your dup2's that don't mention fd 0 are going to have any effect on the child's stdin. You move a bunch of pipe fds around, but you never put any of them on stdin (0) or stdout (1). And I don't get why the malloc is a multiple of 3 while pipe fds come in pairs, not triplets... could you try a version with just one child process and make that work first?